# Trying to move 2D object with accelerometer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to direct my player when he is in the air. So I maded a method called `CheckTilt()` which is called in `FixedUpdate()` which is basically checking to see if the tablet has been moved in the x direction. The condition inside of `CheckTilt()` is based on a `bool` variable called `isGrounded` which basically is false when the player is airborne and true otherwise that part works fine. However, I cannot get the player to move based on the accelerometer. Here is my method:

```
 public void checkTilt()
{
    if (!isGrounded)
    {

            float tiltSpeed = 10.0f;
            float x = Input.acceleration.x;
            Vector2 tilted = new Vector2(x, 0);
            myRigidBody.AddForce(tilted * tiltSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Other Info: I'm building this for **android** device, and have tested it with the unity remote.

Comment: remote will not work at all. you need to build through to device

Comment: I'll make a build then. If i were to be moving a 2D object in the x direction would that work though?

Comment: ok, so that's the answer -i'll put it in to keep the board tidy.

Comment: hey ... DONT FORGET the gyro function may actually be MUCH BETTER for you ..  Contents/Documentation/en/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-userAcceleration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately the answer is just that **nothing like that works with the Unity remote** - you must build to try it.

Re your other question: it's almost impossible to guess the "parity".  you have to try it, and if that is not right, just multiply by -1f.  (What I do is include a UI button on screen, which, swaps the parity - but really just build twice until you get it!)

---

## "I'm still not getting any movement when moved..."

it's an incredible pain in the ass getting the axes right.  YES, on fact, it is 100% a fact that you will need to read all 3 axis, even if a 2D game.

Don't forget that

## Apple STUPIDLY USE Z-BACKWARDS orientation ...

because they are utter idiots who have never worked in the game industry.

[image]

[DOCO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html)

But you will almost certainly have to do this:

You are familiar with using the Canvas / UI system, right?  if not tell me.

1) make a canvas and add three Text fields

2) do this

```
public Text showX;
public Text showY;
public Text showZ;
```

and then

```
showX.text = yourAccelerometer.x.ToString("f2");
.. same for the others ..
```

It seems like a pain but I assure, it's the ONLY WAY to figure out what the hell is going on.

Comment: This seems like a solution, I will build it out a few times and update the thread. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not getting any movement when moved. Would I need to detect the acceleration of z even though it's 2D

Comment: you rock .. dude did you get a good result?  there's also a thing you can do with like making your own axes, I will get some example code.  it is a hellova business making gyros/accels work.  no matter how often one does it is one of those things "new every time".  it may well be worth considering buying something like this for 10 bucks https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1754

Comment: Hell yeah! Thanks for that link I'll check it out